# Bootstrap carrousel spinning like crazy

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have some trouble with a bootstrap carousel. When I use the data-interval="true" option the carousel starts automatic as it should. The problem it is spinning like crazy.

How do I make the pause time of the carousel longer?

[You can see the problem](http://loopvoorcliniclowns.be/problem.html)

Code I'm using:

```
<div id="myCarousel2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="true">
```

I did tried to override the .JS files and .css files but this won't help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Options can be passed via data attributes or JavaScript. For data
>   attributes, append the option name to data-, as in data-interval=""

You're using `data-interval="true"` this should be a **number** or **"false"** (if you don't want it to automatically cycle).

For instance > `data-interval="2000"` and the default is **5000** without setting any `data-attribute`.

See working example Snippet and [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-options).

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Museo;
  src: url("../fonts/Museo-500.otf") format("opentype");
}
body {
  color: #383838;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.white {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
p {
  line-height: 20px!important;
}
.excerpt {
  line-height: 24px!important;
}
.jumbotron-header {
  height: 600px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 18px!important;
}
.jumbotron-content {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-top: 480px;
  text-align: center;
}
.formulier {
  padding: 40px 0px;
}
.countdown {
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
}
.ribbon {
  height: 184px;
}
.img-nieuws {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-right: 15px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.img-nieuws-featured {
  height: 200px;
  padding: 15px;
}
.avatar {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.logo {
  margin-top: -15px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.blue {
  color: #1078b9;
}
.blue-light {
  background-color: #93d7e8;
}
.blue-dark {
  background-color: #1178b9;
  border-top: solid 16px #93d7e8;
  border-bottom: solid 16px #93d7e8;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.blue-line {
  border-bottom: solid 2px #93d7e8;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.red {
  color: #dc011b;
}
.red-light {
  background-color: #e9021d;
}
.red-dark {
  background-color: #e9021d;
  border-top: solid 16px #cb0119;
  border-bottom: solid 16px #cb0119;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.orange-dark {
  background-color: #fde0c5;
  border-top: solid 16px #cb0119;
  border-bottom: solid 16px #cb0119;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.deelnemer {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e9021d;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.btn-social-icon {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.btn-default {
  background-color: #f6ad65!important;
  color: #FFFFFF!important;
}
.nieuws-facebook {
  height: 400px;
}
.laatste-nieuws {
  background-color: #e9021d;
  line-height: 34px;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}
a.whitelink:link,
a.whitelink:hover,
a.whitelink:visited,
a.whitelink:active {
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.orange {
  color: #f29400;
}
.orange-light {
  color: #f8b333;
}
.orange-dark {
  background-color: #f29400;
  border-top: solid 16px #f8b333;
  border-bottom: solid 16px #f8b333;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.sponsoren {
  height: 200px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
.form-control {
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0px 0px 2px 0px;
}
.control-label {
  font-weight: normal;
}
/* SPACEING */

.single {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.formulier {
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.biografie {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.footer {
  margin-top: 40px;
  border-top: 16px solid #dc011b;
  ;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
ul.footer-links > li {
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
ul.footer-links > li > a {
  color: #000;
}
.space {
  padding-left: 25px!important;
  font-size: 16px!important;
  line-height: 90px!important;
}
img.post-header {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
img.box {
  border-radius: 15px!important;
  border: 2px solid #dc011b;
  height: 98px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
/* LEADERBOARDS */

.number {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.number-1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.number-2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.number-3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-right: 17px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.number-rest {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 28px;
}
.number-rest-10 {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 18px;
}
.gold {
  font-size: 26px;
  background-image: url('../images/gold.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.silver {
  font-size: 22px;
  background-image: url('../images/silver.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 11px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.bronze {
  font-size: 18px;
  background-image: url('../images/bronze.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 11px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.rest {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 14px;
}
ul {
  margin-left: -20px;
  font-style: Museo;
}
.leaderboards > ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: -40px!important;
}
.leaderboards {
  line-height: 36px;
}
img.pull-left {
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.red-light-border {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
h2 a {
  color: #ed2e38;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  font-family: Museo;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 46px;
}
h1.space-top {
  margin-top: -10px;
}
h1.post-title {
  font-size: 32px;
}
h3 {
  line-height: 32px;
}
.big {
  font-size: 38px;
}
.white {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #383838;
}
.img-right {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.grey-dark {
  background-color: #262f38;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
.carousel-control {
  background: none!important;
}
#marathonlopers {
  height: 590px;
}
.btn {
  font-family: Museo;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.btn-full {
  width: 100%;
}
.btn-white {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #383838!important;
}
.btn-search {
  background-color: #0c6094;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.btn-xl {
  height: 100px!important;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 20px!important;
  width: 100%;
}
.full-width {
  width: 100%!important;
}
.h3-btn {
  margin-top: 0px!important;
}
/* THEME DEBUG */

.grey {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
.btn-default {
  background-color: #1178b9;
  color: #383838;
  border: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.btn-danger {
  background-color: #dc011b;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
/* NAVBAR */

.navbar-header {
  width: 160px;
}
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #dc011b;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 !important;
  font-family: Museo;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 0px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #dc011b;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:active {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #cb0119;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #cb0119;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #dc011b;
  border: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #dc011b;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > .divider {
  background-color: #dc011b;
}
.dropdown-menu > li.kopie > a {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #cb0119;
  outline: 0;
}
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}
.dropdown-submenu > a:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #333;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  float: right;
  height: 0;
  margin-right: -10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 0;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
  border-left-color: #555;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
/* TABLES */

.table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.table > thead > tr > th,
.table > tbody > tr > th,
.table > tfoot > tr > th,
.table > thead > tr > td,
.table > tbody > tr > td,
.table > tfoot > tr > td {
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.table > thead > tr > th {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.table > caption + thead > tr:first-child > th,
.table > colgroup + thead > tr:first-child > th,
.table > thead:first-child > tr:first-child > th,
.table > caption + thead > tr:first-child > td,
.table > colgroup + thead > tr:first-child > td,
.table > thead:first-child > tr:first-child > td {} .table > tbody + tbody {} .table .table {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.table-condensed > thead > tr > th,
.table-condensed > tbody > tr > th,
.table-condensed > tfoot > tr > th,
.table-condensed > thead > tr > td,
.table-condensed > tbody > tr > td,
.table-condensed > tfoot > tr > td {
  padding: 5px;
}
.table-bordered {} .table-bordered > thead > tr > th,
.table-bordered > tbody > tr > th,
.table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th,
.table-bordered > thead > tr > td,
.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td,
.table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td {} .table-bordered > thead > tr > th,
.table-bordered > thead > tr > td {} .table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  color: #383838;
}
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #CCC;
  color: #383838;
}
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
table col[class*="col-"] {
  position: static;
  display: table-column;
  float: none;
}
table td[class*="col-"],
table th[class*="col-"] {
  position: static;
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
}
.table > thead > tr > td.active,
.table > tbody > tr > td.active,
.table > tfoot > tr > td.active,
.table > thead > tr > th.active,
.table > tbody > tr > th.active,
.table > tfoot > tr > th.active,
.table > thead > tr.active > td,
.table > tbody > tr.active > td,
.table > tfoot > tr.active > td,
.table > thead > tr.active > th,
.table > tbody > tr.active > th,
.table > tfoot > tr.active > th {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.table-hover > tbody > tr > td.active:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr > th.active:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.active:hover > td,
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > .active,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.active:hover > th {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}
.table > thead > tr > td.success,
.table > tbody > tr > td.success,
.table > tfoot > tr > td.success,
.table > thead > tr > th.success,
.table > tbody > tr > th.success,
.table > tfoot > tr > th.success,
.table > thead > tr.success > td,
.table > tbody > tr.success > td,
.table > tfoot > tr.success > td,
.table > thead > tr.success > th,
.table > tbody > tr.success > th,
.table > tfoot > tr.success > th {
  background-color: #dff0d8;
}
.table-hover > tbody > tr > td.success:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr > th.success:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.success:hover > td,
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > .success,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.success:hover > th {
  background-color: #d0e9c6;
}
.table > thead > tr > td.info,
.table > tbody > tr > td.info,
.table > tfoot > tr > td.info,
.table > thead > tr > th.info,
.table > tbody > tr > th.info,
.table > tfoot > tr > th.info,
.table > thead > tr.info > td,
.table > tbody > tr.info > td,
.table > tfoot > tr.info > td,
.table > thead > tr.info > th,
.table > tbody > tr.info > th,
.table > tfoot > tr.info > th {
  background-color: #d9edf7;
}
.table-hover > tbody > tr > td.info:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr > th.info:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.info:hover > td,
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > .info,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.info:hover > th {
  background-color: #c4e3f3;
}
.table > thead > tr > td.warning,
.table > tbody > tr > td.warning,
.table > tfoot > tr > td.warning,
.table > thead > tr > th.warning,
.table > tbody > tr > th.warning,
.table > tfoot > tr > th.warning,
.table > thead > tr.warning > td,
.table > tbody > tr.warning > td,
.table > tfoot > tr.warning > td,
.table > thead > tr.warning > th,
.table > tbody > tr.warning > th,
.table > tfoot > tr.warning > th {
  background-color: #fcf8e3;
}
.table-hover > tbody > tr > td.warning:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr > th.warning:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.warning:hover > td,
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > .warning,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.warning:hover > th {
  background-color: #faf2cc;
}
.table > thead > tr > td.danger,
.table > tbody > tr > td.danger,
.table > tfoot > tr > td.danger,
.table > thead > tr > th.danger,
.table > tbody > tr > th.danger,
.table > tfoot > tr > th.danger,
.table > thead > tr.danger > td,
.table > tbody > tr.danger > td,
.table > tfoot > tr.danger > td,
.table > thead > tr.danger > th,
.table > tbody > tr.danger > th,
.table > tfoot > tr.danger > th {
  background-color: #f2dede;
}
.table-hover > tbody > tr > td.danger:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr > th.danger:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.danger:hover > td,
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > .danger,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.danger:hover > th {
  background-color: #ebcccc;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .ribbon {
    height: 344px;
  }
  .nieuws-facebook {
    height: 460px;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    display: inline;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    display: inline;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: red;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: 2px;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #333;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .dropdown-menu {
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
  .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu {
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
  .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu {
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
  li.dropdown.open {
    border: 0px solid red;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  ul.nav li:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  #navbar {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-header grey-dark">
  <div id="myCarousel2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item jumbotron-content" style="background-image:url('http://www.loopvoorcliniclowns.be/nym-2016/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/result.jpg');width: 100%;height: 600px;display: cover;background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;">
        <div class="container">
          <h2></h2>

          <h1>Onbetaalbaar, de lach van een kind</h1>


          <h2>

                  </h2>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item jumbotron-content" style="background-image:url('http://www.loopvoorcliniclowns.be/nym-2016/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Medaille-2015.jpg');width: 100%;height: 600px;display: cover;background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;">
        <div class="container">
          <h2></h2>

          <h1>Voor jou in 2016?</h1>


          <h2>

            </h2>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item jumbotron-content active left" style="background-image:url('http://www.loopvoorcliniclowns.be/nym-2016/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Neus-slider.jpg');width: 100%;height: 600px;display: cover;background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;">
        <div class="container">
          <h2></h2>

          <h1>Loop NY Marathon voor Cliniclowns!</h1>


          <h2>

            </h2>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item jumbotron-content next left" style="background-image:url('http://www.loopvoorcliniclowns.be/nym-2016/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/30C8298-94_opt.jpg');width: 100%;height: 600px;display: cover;background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;">
        <div class="container">
          <h2></h2>

          <h1>Cliniclown in actie</h1>


          <h2>

            </h2>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item jumbotron-content" style="background-image:url('http://www.loopvoorcliniclowns.be/nym-2016/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Five-boroughs.jpg');width: 100%;height: 600px;display: cover;background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;">
        <div class="container">
          <h2></h2>

          <h2>

            </h2>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control hidden-xs" href="#myCarousel2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>

    <a class="right carousel-control hidden-xs" href="#myCarousel2" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="orange-dark">
  <div class="jumbotron-h1"></div>
  <div id="marathonlopers" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <div class="container">Other caroucel slide</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="container">Other caroucel slide</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control hidden-xs" href="#marathonlopers" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>

    <a class="right carousel-control hidden-xs" href="#marathonlopers" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem and glad I could help.